# .htaccess rule to forward only if old url entered

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Here's a tricky one for y'all. I have a WordPress site installed on my server in the following directory:

public_html/priestessentrepreneur/dsa/blogdsa

I have divinesparkastrology.com pointed to public_html/priestessentrepreneur/dsa

I have priestessastrology.com pointed to public_html/priestessentrepreneur/dsa/blogdsa

So, my (singular) WordPress installation used to have the site URL set to http://www.divinesparkastrology.com/blogdsa but I recently changed it to http://www.priestessastrology.com/. When you type in http://www.divinesparkastrology.com/ you are correctly forward to the new url, http://www.priestessastrology.com/. However, if you try to go directly to http://www.divinesparkastrology.com/blogdsa it says Nothing Found.

I want http://www.divinesparkastrology.com/blogdsa and all of its subfolders and files to point to their new location at http://www.priestessastrology.com/ (the directory structure hasn't ever changed, only the base URL changed). How do I update the .htaccess file so that the new url still works properly, but if and only if the user has entered the old URL they are forwarded to the new one?

Edit: here's what's currently in my /dsa .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^divinesparkastrology\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.divinesparkastrology\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.priestessastrology\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

And here's what's in my /dsa/blogdsa .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `RewriteRule` to the WordPress .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# added line
RewriteRule ^blogdsa/?$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blogdsa/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

**Note:** that you will never be able to access a `blogdsa` WordPress page with this rule in place.

Comment: this makes the new site load very slow and without any CSS

Comment: You still have code references (CSS) to `blogdsa`. If I were you, I'd remove all references to `blogdsa` and use the rule above for a short time. Trust me, that rule is not what makes WordPress slow :)

Comment: So, I used the search and replace plugin to replace all references of priestessentrepreneur.com/dsa/blogdsa with priestess astrology.com. After this, the above rules worked in getting www.divinesparkastrology.com/blogdsa to forward to www.priestessastrology.com and the site loaded quickly again.

But they caused a new problem: www.priestessastrology.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Cindy-close-up-with-blue-earrings.jpg no longer loaded, nor did the Edit links on pages.

Comment: Furthermore, old spidered links like www.divinesparkastrology.com/blogdsa/category/solar-eclipse still did not point to their correct new location (www.priestessastrology.com/category/solar-eclipse).

There is no reference to blogdsa in any CSS file within my theme folder. The only results for "blogdsa" with the search and replace plugin (i.e., in my database), are in wp_commentmeta and a couple of places where it uses the entire server directory structure (e.g., /home/priestess/www/www/dsa/blogdsa/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/apolo-ohno.jpg). What's going on?

Comment: Migrating WordPress to a different domain is a non-trivial task. For redirecting a directory to another directory, what I have works. The rest deals with your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it at the .htaccess level. Do it at the httpd.conf level, with a very basic

```
NameVirtualHost x.x.x.x
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x>
    ServerName www.divinesparkastrology.com
    ServerAlias divinesparkastrology.com *.divinesparkastrology.com
    RedirectPermanent / http://priestessastrology.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This way you can do your redirects without having to mess with sharing .htaccess with wordpress or having the two sites sharing a common structure. Apache will take care of redirecting all requests to the new server name without having to load/parse/rewrite the .htaccess file on every single hit.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your the top of your .htaccess file in the **public_html/priestessentrepreneur/dsa/blogdsa** folder. before any existing rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if request is on the divinesparkastrology domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?divinesparkastrology\.com [NC]
#and it is for a folder starting with blogdsa
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(blogdsa.*)$ [NC]
#redirect them to the same folder on the priestressastrology site
RewriteRule .* http://www.priestessastrology.com/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Edit: modified to include just divinesparkastrology without www and, more importantly, since blogdsa is a part of both sites, the .htaccess should be placed in blogdsa directory, not the dsa dir.

Comment: this doesn't seem to have any affect, either before or after the current code that is in that file (see edited post above)

Comment: Please use the latest edits above, and most importantly place these changes in the `blogdsa` .htaccess above all the other rules. You should leave the .htaccess file in the dsa directory as is.

Comment: I left everything else as is and added that above my WordPress rules and still no effect